# Angular 4 Sanitizing/escaping query parameters

Tags: angular, escaping, sanitization, url-parameters, query-string

How do i securely use any query parameters that i receive? I have read about DOM sanitizing in Angular 4, but i can't find anything about securely using query parameters in angular 4.

**Example:**

```
https://www.myangularproject.com/?parameter1=value
```

I want to avoid that people inject there own code or scripts as `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the parameter can be securely casted to the type of data that you expect it to be (if you expect a number, make sure '+queryParam' is not `NaN`, and so on), never use `eval` on data from the queryParams. You can be rest assured about putting queryParams values inside the DOM, as it is being sanitized by Angular before interpolating it to the view. This, I think, should do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you are saying that i should escape it myself and that there is no automatic Angular sanitation for query parameters? This wasn't clear in the docs of Angular, hence the question

Comment: There is no need in "sanitizing" it, just don't use `eval` on it and make sure to cast it to the expected type (because queryParams always emit strings). So essentially, yes, you do not have much work to do on this one